# Regex to match three words in cyrillic that could contain a hyphen

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that matches 3 words in cyrillic that can contain also hyphens in C#.

**Matches**:
"АБ АБ А",
"А-Б А-Б А-Б", "А-Б-А АБ АБ", etc.

**Doesn't match**:
"АБ АБ", "А-Б АБ", "АБ АБ-", etc.

So far I have a regex for cyrillic letters only: **^[\u0400-\u04FF]+$**

Comment: so what's the problem..use :- `[\u0400-\u04FF-]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's *elaborate the rules*:

> - Word must start from letter, end by letter
> - Word can contain any number of 
>     hyphens; each hyphen must be surrounded by letters (*starting*, *dangling* or
>     *doubled* hyphens are not allowed)

so for the *single word* we have

```
  [\u0400-\u04FF](-?[\u0400-\u04FF]+)*
```

some examples:

```
  АБ      // correct
  АБ-А-АБ // correct (with hyphens)
  Z       // incorrect: non cyrillic letter
  -А      // incorrect: starting hyphen
  А-      // incorrect: dangling hyphen
  А--Б    // incorrect: double hyphen
```

now, for words: we want *exactly three* words separated by *any number* of white spaces `\s`:

```
  ^[\u0400-\u04FF](-?[\u0400-\u04FF]+)*(\s+[\u0400-\u04FF](-?[\u0400-\u04FF]+)*){2}$
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way, what would be the case if I want exactly one white space between the words?

Comment: @Yulian: in case of *exactly one* space, just change `\s+` to `\s`